# What does "más calor que follando" mean?

Tags: expresiones, españa, coloquialismos

I saw this sentence on my crush's snapchat. He is Spanish and lives in Andalucía.

I did a translation, I think it means "the weather is hotter than f**king (or having sex)". Is it correct?

Comment: *"Hot as f\*ck"* seems reasonable, though i've never heard this expression before.  Where did you hear/read this?

Comment: It sounds more like someone took an English phrase and translated it poorly to Spanish. Did this come from a native speaker?

Comment: Yes, my friend is Spanish. He lives in Andalucia.

Comment: To me, it sounds like something an Andalusian might say. Indeed, when you are having sex it gets pretty hot :)

Comment: A quick search shows a plethora of elaborations. _Hace más calor que follando en un sofá de escay_. And/or _debajo de un hule/plástico/techo de uralita_. And/or _en medio de una era_. The addenda make you sweat just by thinking about it.

Comment: your translation is right; it's an hyperbolic form I've personally never heard, but it literally means "it's hotter than having sex", with "hot" meaning only the body sensation of warmth rather than "hot as f*ck" where "hot" is referring to a person being sexually attractive

Comment: Estamos haciendo metalenguaje, este es un sitio serio. No veo para qué poner "_f*cking_" cuando la palabra "_fucking_" existe y es nuestro objeto de estudio.

Comment: I do not think this can be a direct translation from English. With an adjective we would say as X as fuck, or fucking X but Xer than fuck seems odd to me. Perhaps in other dialects it might be used

Comment: I asked who posted this already. He said he compared the hot weather to the temperature when having sex.

Answer (score 3):

Follando is equal to have sex.

La expresion se refiere a que estas en un lugar muy caliente de manera morbosa.
Is similar to : I have more heat than having sex